# Remote Desktop Services required?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running a Windows 2012 R2 Server set up in November 2013. A while back I started getting warnings from some icon in the notification area informing me that "[The] Remote Desktop Service trial period will end in X days". This warning pops up every time that I or any of my co-workers connect to the machine in question. This has me a bit puzzled. At first, I assumed that I wouldn't have to worry about it, but as the deadline comes ever nearer, I'm growing a bit concerned.

Do I need "Remote Desktop Service" in order to connect to the machine from a remote location or can I still manage the machine after the trial period expires? The physical location of the server in question makes it somewhat troublesome for me to manage it without any form of remote desktop tool.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There is licensing specific for RDS on servers.  Check with Microsoft online and they should be able to tell you what is required.